# Getting Cursor position in Tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I've an entry widget in my tkinter program. Let's say I typed about 10 words in it and went to another entry widget for typing. Now when I click back on my entry widget 1 (previous one), cursor goes to the character as per click position. How do I get cursor position index for that widget ? I referred to http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm documentation but couldn't find a suitable method for getting cursor position.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`Entry.index()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111190045id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.index-method)  method to get the index of the current `INSERT` position.

```
from Tkinter import *

def get_info():
    print e.index(INSERT)

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
Button(root, text="get info", command=get_info).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for. I'm new to tkinter and hence couldn't understand while reading its description.