# How can I find the boundaries of a paragraph with Python `string.find()`?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a corpus of text, which is separated into paragraphs with `\nn`.

```
\n\n"Well done, Mrs. Martin!" thought Emma.  "You know what you are about."\n\n"And when she had come away, Mrs. Martin was so very kind as to send\nMrs. Goddard a beautiful goose--the finest goose Mrs. Goddard had\never seen.  Mrs. Goddard had dressed it on a Sunday, and asked all\nthe three teachers, Miss Nash, and Miss Prince, and Miss Richardson,\nto sup with her."\n\n"Mr. Martin, I suppose, is not a man of information beyond the line\nof his own business? He does not read?"\n\n"Oh yes!--that is, no--I do not know--but I believe he has\nread a good deal--but not what you would think any thing of.\nHe reads the Agricultural Reports, and some other books that lay\nin one of the window seats--but he reads all _them_ to himself.\nBut sometimes of an evening, before we went to cards, he would read\nsomething aloud out of the Elegant Extracts, very entertaining.\nAnd I know he has read the Vicar of Wakefield.  He never read the\nRomance of the Forest, nor The Children of the Abbey.  He had never\nheard of such books before I mentioned them, but he is determined\nto get them now as soon as ever he can."\n\nThe next question was--\n\n"What sort of looking man is Mr. Martin?"
```

Or if printed,

```
"Well done, Mrs. Martin!" thought Emma.  "You know what you are about."

"And when she had come away, Mrs. Martin was so very kind as to send
Mrs. Goddard a beautiful goose--the finest goose Mrs. Goddard had
ever seen.  Mrs. Goddard had dressed it on a Sunday, and asked all
the three teachers, Miss Nash, and Miss Prince, and Miss Richardson,
to sup with her."

"Mr. Martin, I suppose, is not a man of information beyond the line
of his own business? He does not read?"

"Oh yes!--that is, no--I do not know--but I believe he has
read a good deal--but not what you would think any thing of.
He reads the Agricultural Reports, and some other books that lay
in one of the window seats--but he reads all _them_ to himself.
But sometimes of an evening, before we went to cards, he would read
something aloud out of the Elegant Extracts, very entertaining.
And I know he has read the Vicar of Wakefield.  He never read the
Romance of the Forest, nor The Children of the Abbey.  He had never
heard of such books before I mentioned them, but he is determined
to get them now as soon as ever he can."

The next question was--

"What sort of looking man is Mr. Martin?"
```

Given a certain paragraph, I would like to know where the paragraph's boundaries are. That is, I would like to find where the paragraph is by the line breaks `\n\n`.

My goal is for my cursor to click on a certain paragraph, and I will know the boundaries of this paragraph based on the location of `\n\n`.

```
import string
string.find("\n\n")
```

will output the locations for where the spaces are within the string. But what about a certain paragraph? If I "click" on the fourth paragraph (at `Vicar of Wakefield`), how can I search for the first `\n\n` above this and search for the first `\n\n` below this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the position `pos` where you "clicked" inside the long text string, then you can use `str.find` and `str.rfind()` to solve your question.

To look "forward" you would do a:

```
string.find("\n\n", pos)  # searches for "\n\n" starting from position `pos`, returning the first match
```

and "backward" you would do a:

```
string.rfind("\n\n", 0, pos) # searches for "\n\n" from the beginning up-to `pos` but will return you the last match
```

For documentation on both methods look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: Any ideas on finding out the position where one "clicked"?

Comment: That requires you to give more context around the "system" you have. How do you display the paragraph? How do you handle input devices? 

I would post that as another question.

Comment: I am going to use TkInter as an interactive GUI. Basically, input the text via Text Widget, and allow the user to "click" a paragraph.

Comment: I am not familiar with TkInter. In some cases GUI widgets have methods that respond to "click" or other events, and report a lots of good info, but I can't help you on that. Please post a separate question. I believe my answer is compliant with the OP.

Comment: Actually, you should be able to use something from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023744/getting-cursor-position-in-tkinter-entry-widget](this post). Basically using the text.index(INSERT) call. See also [http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm](this other one).

Comment: Perfect! This should work well! INSERT or CURRENT is what I'm looking for, I believe