# 「python tkinter entryBOX」 How to get a string before input cursor in entrybox?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

"python tkinter entry" How to get a string before a input cursor in entrybox?

entry.get(0,tk.INSERT)

TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def get():
    print(entry.get()[:entry.index("insert")])

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=get)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It gets the contents of the entry then uses string slicing to get all of the characters before `entry.index("insert")`, which is the insert cursor's position.
For more info please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023744/getting-cursor-position-in-tkinter-entry-widget) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729040/11106801).